# Why do I get these hyphens?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make 3 buttons using divs, and align them horizontally using percentages. I managed to do that, but I get these hyphens between the divs. The hyphens appear only when I use 'display: inline-block;', but without it I didn't manage to align them this way. Here is the HTML, coresponing CSS and a screenshot below.

[image: hyphens between divs]

```
<a href="www.google.com">
    <div class="home_buttons" id="book_app_button" >
        <p>book appointment now</p>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="www.facebook.com">
    <div class="home_buttons" id="order_cl_button" >
        <p>order contact lenses</p>
    </div>  
</a>

<a href="www.reddit.com">
    <div class="home_buttons" id="contact_us_button" >
        <p>contact us</p>
    </div>
</a>


<style>
.home_buttons {
    width: 10%;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 11%;
    margin-left: 11%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 90%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: inspect them using dev tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are not hyphens, but the default underline of your `<a>`elements.
You can remove them with `text-decoration: none;` in your css

```css
a {
   text-decoration: none;
   }

.home_buttons {
    width: 10%;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 11%;
    margin-left: 11%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 90%;
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com">
    <div class="home_buttons" id="book_app_button" >
        <p>book appointment now</p>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="www.facebook.com">
    <div class="home_buttons" id="order_cl_button" >
        <p>order contact lenses</p>
    </div>  
</a>

<a href="www.reddit.com">
    <div class="home_buttons" id="contact_us_button" >
        <p>contact us</p>
    </div>
</a>
```